# Java applet quiz program-Looping through questions

Tags: java, applet

I am working on a simple Java applet multiple choice quiz that will display a question with three choices.  I am pulling the questions and answers from a text file and want to loop through the questions as the user answers them.  So every time the user hits 'Submit' the program will check the answer then update the labels with a new question.  My question is how do I get the loop to wait on the answer?  Should I put all of the code in the button event handler?  I thought about Cardlayout, but it seemed inefficient. I don't really have any code yet; I'm still in the planning stage.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use JProgressBar to show time-factor!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

- First of all regarding, `"My question is how do I get the loop to wait on the answer?"`, I wouldn't even use a for-loop or any similar loop to solve this.
- I would create a non-GUI class to hold each question, the possible answers and the correct answer. Consider calling it Question. It would have a String field for the question itself, a `List<String>` for possible answers, and either another String for the correct answer, or it could hold an int for the index to the correct answer, or even have the correct answer always be the first one, and be sure to randomize the display of answers.
- Create an ArrayList of this class, `ArrayList<Question>`.
- Read in the file all at once, filling your ArrayList.
- Give your main GUI class an int index variable for iterating through this ArrayList.
- When a submit button is pressed, increment your index and get the next item in the List (if not at the size limit of the List).
- Consider creating a JPanel class for displaying each question and the possible answers, perhaps called QuestionPanel.
- You can either create one display object and swap out the text of your question JLabel and the text of your JRadioButtons. This works nicely if all questions have the same number of possible answers.
- Or you could create multiple QuestionPanels, and swap them via CardLayout.
- There's nothing "inefficient" about a CardLayout. I have no idea what you're talking about here. Care to elaborate what is inefficient about it, and just what you mean by the term "inefficient"?

Comment: I'd probably suggest that a random number be generated bound by the size of the list, or similar method, so that the experience is not identical each use.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: That's not a bad idea. And the program could also randomize the order of the possible answers.

Comment: I used your suggestion and made an arraylist with an int variable to loop through that increments when the button is pressed.  This works fine, thanks!  As for why I thought cardlayout would be inefficient, I would rather build the GUI through code instead of making 50 different panels for 50 questions.  Maybe i am misunderstanding how cardlayout works though.